# Convert Core Erlang forms into Erlang source code string

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, decompiler, coreerlang

I have Core Erlang forms constructs with the `cerl` module. I wish to "decompile" it into an Erlang source code string.

I though I could do something like this:

```
Forms = erl_syntax:form_list(CoreForms),
erl_prettypr:format(Forms).
```

However `erl_syntax:form_list/1` returns an empty list.

Comment: What is `CoreForms`?

Comment: what is the c_erl module? which function are you using? With which parameters?

Comment: The module is named cerl, not c_erl. It is part of the compiler application.

Comment: @pdexter `CoreForms` is a `cerl:cerl()`, a module as Core Erlang AST.

Answer (score 2):

Core Erlang ASTs cannot be handled with the utilities in syntax_tools - those are for normal Erlang ASTs only. For Core Erlang there are two modules (undocumented) for prettyprinting: `core_pp` in the compiler application, similar to `erl_pp` in stdlib, and `cerl_prettypr` in the hipe application (under lib/hipe/cerl/) which is similar to `erl_prettypr` in syntax_tools.

Comment: `core_pp:format/1` converts core Erlang to a core Erlang source string, but I am interested in building a regular Erlang source string.

Comment: @lpil ah, so from core you want to print Erlang? That isn't trivially possible. You cannot 'simply' reconstruct the Erlang source from core.

Comment: As I feared. Thanks for confirming :)